# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _device: The file cannot be accessed by the system

Tags: python, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, ipython, environment

``
So, I'm trying to install ipykernal to my enviroment and I get this error, any suggestions?

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRT1o.png)

I was advised to check if I installed pip zmq and pyzmq but that didn't change anything. Then I created the enviroment again but it doesn't work. I plugged the error in to chatgpt and it said:

heck if the DLL file that is causing the import error (_device.pyd) is accessible to the system. Make sure that the file is not being used by another process and that it has the necessary permissions to be accessed by your Python script.

but I don't know how to.

Comment: Don't know how to do what?  Check if file is used by another process?  Check if file is accessible to system/user?  Please be aware that the answer to these questions will be dependent on you OS environment.  So we will need more information in order to provide suggestions.

Comment: I'm working with anaconda, and jupyter notebook on windows sorry

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by giving permission to all users to be able to access my enviroment folder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).